# How to save x and y position to a jSon file after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my code bellow Im displaying the x and y coordinates when Im dragging "var rec" in a alert box.
Now I wanna save the new coordinates x and y to a jSon file when stoped dragging "var rec".

I started testing with this line of code:

```
dragend.data("dragend").originalPosition

window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container : "container",
        width : 1400,
        height : 1448
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill : 'black'
    });

    var group = new Kinetic.Group({
        draggable: true
    });
    group.add(rect);
    layer.add(group);
    group.on('dragend',function(){
        alert(group.getPosition().x+"/"+group.getPosition().y);
    });
    layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: Provide the html mark up or make a fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Do you have a server you can interact with, or were you hoping to do this on the client side? If the latter, I'm afraid you won't be able to.

Comment: I don't see any json encoding in this code

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Thanks, I dont really understand what you mean, but here is the html code that I use know In my code:    <div id="container"></div>

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Thanks, yes on the client side, if Its possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery plugin [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) that allows you to read and write to a local file.

Stringify you data and save it to file.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(yourObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my code is it the 'var rec' that is my Object. Its says rec is not defined.

Comment: i can not see definition of rec in your snip. where you defined it.

Comment: Thanks, I mean var rect... Is that my Object?

Comment: yup... stringify it like : var data = JSON.stringify(rect);

Comment: Thanks, but I get error var rect is not defined. Could you help me with that?

Comment: sure... show me where you are doing it. as i can see it is locally declared within onLoad function

Comment: Thanks, your line of code is inside window.onload = function() now, and Its not giving me any error. But how do I save it into a file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends for how long you want to save it. You can use the localStorage.

Please, take a look here:
[localStorage Definition and Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Ok, but I dont want to store It like a localStorage

Comment: How do you want to store it? There aren't infinite ways to do so.

Comment: Ok so refer to http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

Comment: Ok, but Its not helping me with my problem.